# Question: Trying to add a layer but fails

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have made a lambda with a layer integrated, like this:

```
    const layer = new lambda.LayerVersion(this, 'session-store-layer', {
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('src/resources'),
      compatibleRuntimes: [lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X],
    });
    layer.addPermission('remote-account-grant', { accountId: '648594647853' });

    const createSessionFunction = new lambda.Function(
      this,
      'CreateSessionHandler',
      {
        runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
        code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('src/functions/createSession'),
        handler: 'index.handler',
        layers: [layer],
        environment: {
          SESSION_STORE_TABLE_NAME: table.tableName,
        },
      }
    );
```

The folder `src/resources` has the package `uuid` and a little function inside on the `utils` folder, I'm trying to use the package `uuid` on the lambda CreateSessionHandler but it does not work... I'm missing something but I don't know what it is .

This is the [code](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/cdk-examples/tree/master/session-store-example) I'm using to learn AWS CDK. Thank you!

This the error I get when I execute the lambda, when I change it to just `ùuid`, like, `const uuid = require('uuid')` I get the same error:

[image]

But the layer is added

[image]

Comment: The code looks ok to me. What error do you see?

Comment: I have updated the question with the error I get

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you don't have a `package.json` with the dependency for `uuid` defined in the `src/functions` folder and instead it's in the `src/resources` folder. Usually you put the `package.json` file in the same folder as the `index.js` file so in this case your functions `createSession, deleteSession, etc.` are not finding the `uuid` module.

I think it will work if you provide a `package.json` for those in `src/functions` or modify the `require` call to go up whatever level you need to to get to the `package.json` in the `resources` folder like - `const uuid = require('../../resources/uuid')`

Answer (score 0):

Answer taken from [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/11417#issuecomment-725482630) adapted to your question.

From AWS documentation: [Including library dependencies in a layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path)

NodeJS layers require a specific file structure. Basically you need to run `npm init` inside a `nodejs` directory, so that you end up with another `node_modules` directory like so:

```
.
├─ src
│    └─ stack.ts  
│    └─ resources           
│         └─ nodejs                   
│              └─ node_modules
|              └─ package.json
│
```

And then pass the path to the `LayerVersion` options:

```
const layer = new lambda.LayerVersion(this, 'session-store-layer', {
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('src/resources'),
  compatibleRuntimes: [lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X],
});
```

And this should do the trick.